# fs.writeFileSync replacement for regular javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, byte, arrays

I am using a code library who's examples use Node.js to write a file to the local file system, like this:

```
fs.writeFileSync('test2.mid', file.toBytes(), 'binary');
```

I am not using Node.js in my project, so i want to make this a js variable that is base64 string instead of a physical file.  How can I do this using only javascript?

file.toBytes() is a function that returns bytes of data to write file.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your question is really unclear. What is the input? What is the desired output? In what environment? (A browser?)

Comment: I want the output to be a base64 string, the input is bytes of data.  Yes, this would be output to the browser

Comment: "bytes of data" in what form? `UInt8Array`? Again, you seem to be holding back quite a lot of detail; more is good.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this with the following code:

```
document.location = 'data:audio/midi;base64,' + btoa(file.toBytes());
```